# VS2015 Solidity Extension: BlockchainUser Error

Tags: solidity, private-blockchain, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Solidity extension to build a dApp. I have created a sample project using the Smart Contract Project template and I'm trying to deploy the smart contract to my private test network. I can connect to my private blockchain network using the remix compiler.

What should I put in the BlockChainUser and password field? Which credential does it use?

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Smart Contract Project setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the solidity extension in Visual Studio 2015 works only with BlockApps. https://www.npmjs.com/package/blockapps-bloc

Correct me if I'm wrong. It would be ideal if I can have it connected to my private blockchain network. Thanks!